# Exclude knots in SunGridEngine

Tags: sungridengine

Using SGE I can exclude a node called "node6" with the option:

```
#$ -l h=!node6
```

Question: Does anyone know how to extend this to more than one node? I really can't find a good HowTo and I'm tired of guessing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wildcard expression to exclude some nodes. For example if you have nodes called node1, node2 ... nodeX; to exclude node2 to node5 you can use :

```
 #$ -l h='!node[2-5]'
```

or to exclude several nodes :

```
 #$ -l h='!(nodeP|nodeQ|...|nodeR)' //P,Q,R in [1,X]
```

Now just find the pattern which matches all the nodes you want to exclude.

Else, you can use a resource quota. To perform that, create a resource quota :

```
qconf -arqs disabledHostsResourceQuota
```

Edit this resource quota to allow a hostgroup (let's call it disabledHosts) to prevent jobs from running :

```
{
   name         disabledHostsResourceQuota
   description  resource quota to disable some hosts
   enabled      TRUE
   limit        hosts {@disabledHosts} to slots=0
}
```

Then create your hostgroup :

```
qconf -ahgrp  disabledHosts
```

and in the "hostlist" field, add all the hosts you want to disable. 
You can then submit your job without any option, that should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately the nodes aren't numbered. Their names are e.g. auger and pauli.

Comment: Then a resource quota would be more appropriate. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I'm sure it would do the trick. But I get an error saying that I'm not the "manager". I guess your solution changes the general behaviour of qsub. But as a user I'm not allowed to do this and it's also not what I want. To be a bit more precise. Some modules which I need for a program to run aren't installed on the two nodes. But I'm not the administrator, so only "lokal" changes are possible.

Comment: Indeed, i was thinking as a manager of sge. Then, to go back from the first idea with the wildcard, if you want to exclude your 2 nodes then the wildcard would be : h='!(auger|pauli)'

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was aiming for. Sometimes it's so easy. You can't imagine how much similar (but not working) combinations I've tried.